# Ionic angular 4 sqlite callback edit scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sqlite

I'm quite new to this, so don't beat me up.
I'm creating an application in Ionic with Angular4, and I'm making use of SQLite.
When I make a select I want to populate a scope variable with the results of my select. I am not being able because I believe they aren't in the same scope.

A bit of my code to show what I have

```
public users = [];

 constructor( ....){}

 otherMethod(){

     db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM players', [], function (resultSet) {

          for(let i = 0; i < resultSet.rows.length; i++) {
                 this.users.push({
                        "player": resultSet.rows.item(i).name
                  });
           }

     });
}
```

The resultSet brings the results I want, so that's okay, but then I can't access "users" the way I usually do.
Tried this with a callback, but no joy.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching about the issue a bit deeper, I got to the conclusion where my call to the "executeSQL" was wrong.

We should not use function(), but use "then()" instead. This means it would stay like this:

```
db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM players', {})
          .then(rows => {
                  console.log("SELECT RESULT", rows);
(...)
```

More info here: https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/10/using-sqlite-in-a-nativescript-angular-2-mobile-app/

Thanks!